# Why is there a boundary integral in integration by parts?

Tags: integration

Someone posted a similar question that does NOT answer my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659119/please-explain-boundary-terms-in-integration-by-parts).

Normally when I see integration by parts, we have two terms, where only one is an integral.

i.e

$$\int_{a}^b u(x) v'(x) dx = \left[u(x) v(x)\right]_{a}^b - \int_{a}^b u'(x) v(x) dx $$

Refer to equation 15 and 16 [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/energy281/BoundaryElementMethod.pdf).
$$\iint{\Omega} \Delta^2 u \; w\; d\Omega $$

What happens when taking integration by parts? Why is the boundary term an integral?

Comment: What is the boundary of the interval $[a,b]$?  How might that related to Gauss/Green/Stokes?

Comment: See for example this Wikipedia page about (the generalised) [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem#Introduction). Essentially, even in one dimension you can see the boundary term as an integral.